# IBM Netezza, How to convert a varchar to a numeric with TO_NUMBER(..., ...)

Tags: sql, database, netezza

I have table called `DART_STG1` in Netezza Database.  The table has a varchar column. I am trying to use the below SQL to convert the varchar into a number, but it always throws an error.

**Code**

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(M12,'99G99') 
FROM   DART_STG1 
WHERE  M12 IS NOT NULL;
```

**Throws an error:**

> ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  Bad numeric input format

What does this error mean?

Comment: What are the results of SELECT DISTINCT M12 FROM DART_STG1 WHERE M12 IS NOT NULL;? Going by the error message, my guess is one or more of the records have data that can't be converted, so maybe you have to do some data massaging to get it to convert properly.

Comment: What do you mean by data massaging?

Comment: I don't get any output when I execute that SQL query.

Comment: I have both NOT NULL and NULL values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The error:**

```
ERROR [HY000] ERROR: Bad numeric input format
```

Is caused because you feeding letters into `TO_NUMBER`.  You are feeding it `99G99` which is not a number.

The program tries to tell you it's not a number by telling you that the numeric input format is bad, as the error very clearly says.

Comment: How to use the TO_NUMBER function for converting string to integer?

Comment: to_number(STORE_NUMBER, '999') - even this returns an error. The actual question here is "What should be the proper input format?" We all know what the error message means in English.

Answer (score 1):

The PDA (Netezza) [Conversion functions page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_conversion_funcs.html) provide examples, and together with the [Template patterns](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_templ_patterns_date_time_conv.html), you can choose the appropriate format.

However I'm getting the same error for my data set. I'm suspecting it's something about the formatting of the values in `STORE_NUMBER` is what Netezza doesn't like.